# Building one array out of several. Monte-Carlo method

Tags: python, numpy, montecarlo

Suppose we have several arrays (in my case, three: `a1`, `a2`, `a3`). We also have one more array of random uniformly distributed numbers, `r`. They are all of the same length. I need to build an array `a` combined of those three initial `a1`, `a2`, `a3` so that if `r[i]` satisfies a particular condition 1, we take `a1[i]` as `a[i]`, if it satisfies condition 2, we take `a2[i]`, and `a3[i]` with condition 3. The three conditions are mutually exclusive.

I've written a for-loop for this:

```
a = empty(len(r))
for i in range(len(r)):
    if r[i] <= p1:
        a[i] = a1[i]
    if p1 < r[i] <= (p1 + p2):
        a[i] = a2[i]
    if r[i] > (p1 + p2):
        a[i] = a3[i]
```

Here conditions 1, 2, 3 are expressed after each "`if ...`". `p1` and `p2` are given numbers. This is part of a Monte-Carlo simulation (arrays `a1`, `a2` and `a3` are also random numbers with a given distribution).
It is too slow, I need to vectorize it somehow, but don't know, how to go about it. Which is the best way?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as 'accepted' if it satisfactorily addresses your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `numpy.select`, which lets you select from multiple conditions:

```
conds = [r <= p1, r <= (p1 + p2), r > (p1 + p2)]
choices = [a1, a2, a3]
a = np.select(conds, choices)
```

In your case, the third condition could actually be any condition that evaluates to True (e.g., `r == r`).

Comment: For small arrays, loops will probably be faster but the question stated that the loop method was too slow and asked how to vectorize, which suggests to me that she is probably using large arrays. In my tests with arrays of 10,000 or more elements, `numpy.select` was in the range of 20 to 30 times faster than explicit loops.